# Найти наименьшее слово из строки на языке С?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
count = 0; posmin = 0; countmin = strlen(str);

for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++){

    if(isalpha(str[i]) == 1){

        if(isalpha(str[i + 1]) == 0){
            count++;
            if(count < countmin){
                countmin = count;
                posmin = i;
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        else count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sergej SadVlad  Форматируйте код, чтобы он выглядел нормально. Он у вас "уплыл" куда-то вправо.

Comment: @Sergej SadVlad  И не ясно, то ли найти минимальное слово, то ли найти минимальную длину слова в строке. Что именно надо найти и каков должен быть результат?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow найти мин слово имеется в виду найти мин по длине

Comment: Почему бы не разбить строку на слова с помощью `strtok`?

Comment: @Sergei И все же минимальное слово или длину минимального слова? И что надо сделать в результате, когда это будет найдено?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нельзя `strtok`, то, например, так (в предположении что слово - только из символов `isalpha`):

```
int main()
{

    char * str = " cbvahv xchnvz jh  jhs sdfjhgbvjhsbvdf sdfh ";
    int count = 0,  posmin = -1,  countmin = strlen(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str);)
    {
        while(str[i] && !isalpha(str[i])) ++i;
        if (str[i] == 0) break;
        int pos = i;
        while(str[i] && isalpha(str[i])) ++i;
        count = i - pos;
        if (count < countmin)
        {
            countmin = count;
            posmin = pos;
        }
    }

    for(int i = posmin; i < posmin+countmin; ++i)
        putchar(str[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Len = %d, pos = %d\n",countmin,posmin);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое @Harry ! А вот выражение while(str[ i ] ) означает "пока элемент принадлежит строке"?

Comment: Просто - пока строка не закончилась (не нулевой завершающий символ). Если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

/*
 * Немного другой подход: определяем слово по границам,
 * а не по набору символов
 */
#define DELIMITERS " \n\r\t,.;!?:-()[]<>{}\"'|+-"

int main( void )
{
    const char text[] = "678 s 1234 56";
    const char *s = text, *minptr = text;
    size_t minlen = strlen( text );

    while( *s ) {
        const char *ptr;

        while( *s && strchr( DELIMITERS, ( *s & CHAR_MAX ) ) ) {
            s++;
        }

        ptr = s;
        while( *s && !strchr( DELIMITERS, ( *s & CHAR_MAX ) ) ) {
            s++;
        }

        if( *ptr && s - ptr < minlen ) {
            minlen = s - ptr;
            minptr = ptr;
        }
    }

    /* minptr - указатель на начало слова, если нужно 
     * вычленить само слово, то это уже отдельно
     */
    printf( "%zu - %s\n", minlen, minptr );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нахождение минимального слова в строке предполагает нахождение его двух характеристик: это указатель на начало слова в строке и длина самого слова.

Для хранения этих характеристик лучше всего создать структуру из двух членов данных и использовать **отдельную функцию**, которая для любой строки будет находить минимальное слово.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как это можно сделать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Position
{
    char *p;
    size_t n;
};

Position min_word(const char *s)
{
    Position min = { NULL, 0 };

    while (*s)
    {
        while (isblank((unsigned char)*s)) ++s;

        if (*s)
        {
            Position current = { ( char * )s, 0 };

            while (*s && !isblank((unsigned char)*s))
            {
                ++current.n;
                ++s;
            }

            if (min.p == NULL || current.n < min.n) min = current;
        }
    }

    return min;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "Hello hi chiao";

    Position min = min_word(s);
    printf("The minimum word in the string is %*.*s with length of %zu\n", 
            min.n, min.n, min.p, min.n);

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
The minimum word in the string is hi with length of 2
```

Обратите внимание, что для нахождения минимального слова в строке не требуется использовать строчные функции, как, например, `strlen`, так как это просто пустая трата времени.